# Size of Apatosaurus

Tags: palaeontology, dinosaurs

What are the current and up-to-date estimates of the size of the big sauropod dinosaur *Apatosaurus* (the biggest species of it) in terms of mass range (weight) and total length? I prefer the answer in metric units.

Answer (score 2):

From the wikipedia page on [*Apatosaurus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apatosaurus):

> Most size estimates are based on specimen CM 3018, the type specimen of *A. louisae*. 
>   In 1936 this was measured to be 21.8 m (72 ft), by measuring the vertebral column.<sup>[5]</sup>
>
> Current estimates are similar, finding that the individual was 21–22.8 m (69–75 ft) long and had a mass of 16.4–22.4 t (16.1–22.0 long tons; 18.1–24.7 short tons).<sup>[6][7][8]</sup>
>
> A 2015 study that estimated the mass of volumetric models of Dreadnoughtus, Apatosaurus, and Giraffatitan estimates CM 3018 at 21.8–38.2 t (21.5–37.6 long tons; 24.0–42.1 short tons), similar in mass to Dreadnoughtus.<sup>[9]</sup>
>
> Past estimates have put the creature's mass as high as 35.0 t (34.4 long tons; 38.6 short tons).<sup>[6]</sup>
>
> Some specimens of A. ajax (such as OMNH 1670) represent individuals 11–30% longer, suggesting masses twice that of CM 3018 or 32.7–72.6 t (32.2–71.5 long tons; 36.0–80.0 short tons), potentially rivalling the largest titanosaurs.<sup>[10]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 5. <sup>["Osteology of Apatosaurus, with special references to specimens in the Carnegie Museum"](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/part/234849#/summary). *Memoirs of the Carnegie Museum.* 11 (4): 1–136, Gilmore, C.W. (1936).</sup>
> 6. <sup>["A new method to calculate allometric length-mass relationships of dinosaurs"](http://www.bioone.org/doi/10.1671/0272-4634%282001%29021%5B0051%3AANMTCA%5D2.0.CO%3B2). *Journal of Vertebrate Paleontology.* 21 (1): 51–52, Seebacher, F. (2001).</sup>
> 7. <sup>["Giants and bizarres: body size of some southern South American Cretaceous dinosaurs"](http://www.miketaylor.org.uk/tmp/papers/Mazzetta-et-al_04_SA-dino-body-size.pdf) *Historical Biology.* 16 (2–4): 71–83, Mazzetta, G.V.; Christiansen, P.; Farina, R.A. (2004).</sup>
> 8. <sup>["Burly Gaits: Centers of mass, stability, and the trackways of sauropod dinosaurs"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1671/0272-4634(2006)26%5B907%3ABGCOMS%5D2.0.CO%3B2). *Journal of Vertebrate Paleontology.* 26 (4): 907–921, Henderson, D.M. (2006).</sup>
> 9. <sup>["Downsizing a giant: re-evaluating Dreadnoughtus body mass"](http://rsbl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/11/6/20150215). *Biology Letters.* 11 (6), Bates, K.T.; Falkingham, P.L.; Macaulay, S.; Brassey, C.; Maidment, S.C.R. (2015).</sup>
> 10. <sup>["A giant, skeletally immature individual of Apatosaurus from the Morrison Formation of Oklahoma"](https://sauroposeidon.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/wedel-2013-svpca-giant-apatosaurus-from-oklahoma.pdf) *61st Symposium on Vertebrate Palaeontology and Comparative Anatomy - Programme and Abstracts:* 40–45, Wedel, M. (2013).</sup>

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the largest Apatosaurus was about 26-27 meters long and may have weighed 50+ metric tons.